# Having trouble installing Python bindings of jq on ubuntu linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, jq

I have been trying to install the Python bindings of jq on ubuntu using pip.

However, when I run the following command, it fails.

`sudo pip install jq`

This is the error message it get.

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-EmO25q/jq/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-RBT2h7-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-m
anaged --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-EmO25q/jq/
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would one use this for over the build in json module?

Answer (score 4):

This gets compiled, you need to install the build dependencies.

`apt-get install autoconf automake build-essential libtool python-dev`

See the Pypi page for more info ... https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jq/0.1.6

Answer (score 0):

Stacked with this problem too. Hence rolled out another binging for others who do not want to compile anything and install irrelevant build toolchains.

**Alternative JQ Python binding is called [JQpy](https://baterflyrity.github.io/jqpy/).**

### Installation

```bash
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install jq
pip install jqpy
```

### Example

```py
>>> from jqpy import jq
>>> jq('.results[] | {age, city}', {
                "timestamp": 1234567890,
                "report": "Age Report",
                "results": [
                        { "name": "John", "age": 43, "city": "TownA" },
                        { "name": "Joe",  "age": 10, "city": "TownB" }
                ]
        })
[{'age': 43, 'city': 'TownA'}, {'age': 10, 'city': 'TownB'}]
```